# Django Models (1054, "Unknown column in 'field list'")

Tags: python, django, django-models

No idea why this error is popping up. Here are the models I created -

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Shows(models.Model):
    showid= models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, db_index=True)
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=256, db_index=True)
    aka   = models.CharField(max_length=256, db_index=True)
    score = models.FloatField()

class UserShow(models.Model):
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User)
    show  = models.ForeignKey(Shows)
```

Here is the view from which I access these models -

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def user_page(request, username):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except:
        raise Http404('Requested user not found.')

    shows     = user.usershow_set.all()
    template  = get_template('user_page.html')
    variables = Context({
        'username': username,
        'shows'   : shows})
    output = template.render(variables)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

At this point I get an error -

**OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'appname_usershow.show_id' in 'field list'")**

As you see this column is not even present in my models? Why this error?

Comment: Strange. Usually you get a model validation error if you declare `id` as a field in a model. I am referring to the first field of the `Shows` model. Can you check again?

Comment: that was a typo. it should have been 'showid'. Coming back, syncdb command ends up creating the models in the DB. No errors at this stage. Only when the view is invoked, this error comes out...

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error? I'd like to know which line inside your view is raising it.

Comment: @movieyoda: See my answer below. Something is going wrong in your template. Can you edit your question and post the template code?

Comment: @Manjo Fixed it myself. Apparently any changes to the models when updated through syncdb does not change (as in update/modify) the actual tables. So I dropped the relevant DB & ran syncdb on empty DB. now it works fine :) Thanks all...

Comment: @movieyoda: yep, syncdb will not act on existing tables. Have a look at south for database migrations.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As @inception said my tables schema had changed & running `syncdb` did not update already created tables.

Apparently any changes to the models when updated through `syncdb` does not change (as in update/modify) the actual tables. So I dropped the relevant DB & ran `syncdb` on empty DB. Now it works fine. :)

For others, [**SOUTH**](http://south.aeracode.org/) data migration tool for Django seems to be favorite option. It seems to provide options which django models & `syncdb` falls short on. Must check out...

**Update 29th Sept 2019**: From Django 1.7 upwards, migrations are built into the core of Django. If you are running a previous lower version of Django, you can find the repository on [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/andrewgodwin/south/src/default/).

Answer (score 28):

maybe your tables schema has been changed? Also, running `syncdb` does not update already created tables.

You might need to drop all the tables & then run `syncdb` again. Also remember to take backup of your data!!

Comment: +1, This saved me a lot of hair-pulling (after spending far too long with the same problem)

Answer (score 6):

Normally I get this when when I'm trying to access field which doesn't exist in Database.

Check if the field exist in the database. If you change model and perform syncdb it won't update the database, I'm not sure if that's the case.

On other note Django offers shortcut to replace try/except block in your code using get_object_or_404. (available in django.shortcuts )

```
try:
     user = User.objects.get(username=username)
except:
     raise Http404('Requested user not found.')
```

can be changed to:

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
```

Comment: This is essentially what happens when trying to use Django Rest Framework serializers. Make sure if you have a serializer that subclasses `ModelSerializer`, that you migrate any changes to the Models before writing your serializer classes (or just comment anything related to the serializer, migrate, then uncomment).

Answer (score 4):

I have met the same problems:

First, run

```
manage.py sqlall [appname]
```

and you can find:

```
`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
```

and I add the column manual:

```
ALTER TABLE tb_realtime_data ADD id integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

and then it worked.

I think django will add the column called id itself.

> For convenience, each model is given an autoincrementing primary key field named id unless you explicitly specify primary_key=True on a field (see the section titled “AutoField” in Appendix A).

you can click [here](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/appendixB.html) for details.

Good luck.

Comment: Can you please enlighten me how you added that line and where it needs to be added?

Comment: I am very sorry that I reply you today. Ok, this is a good question. You use it when you want to use django ORM to access the database which is created by _handed_ not django. I mean that you’ve defined a model, you’ll use this API any time you need to access the database. But the database is not created by django ORM. When this, you should add a column called `id` to the **table**. You can connect to the database by using sql directly, I think.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same error like you posted above with MySQL database back-end, after long time of resolving this error, I ended up with below solution.

1. Manually added column to database through workbench with name exactly the same as it is shown in your error message.
2. After that run below command

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Now migrations will be successfully created

3. After that run below command

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Now every thing works fine without any data lose issue

Answer (score 3):

In the appropriate field explicitly set

```
primary_key = True
```

Comment: yeah, for my case, I am having a table which doesnt have primary key causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old question but you might find the below useful anyway:
Check the database, you're most likely missing the `show_id` in the `appname_usershow` table.

This could occur when you change or add a field but you forget running migration.

OR

When you're accessing a non managed table and you're trying to add a `ForeignKey` to your model.
Following the example above:

```
class UserShow(models.Model):
    # some attributes ...
    show = models.ForeignKey(Show, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'appname_departments'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a late response but hopefully someone will find this useful.

I was working on Django REST APIs using DB models. When I added a new column to my existing model(said column already existed in the db table from the start), I received the error shown below:
*"Unknown column ',column name>' in 'field list'"executed".*

What I missed was migrating the model over to the database.

So I executed the following commands from python terminal:

1. *py -3 manage.py makemigrations* ---> It will not allow NULL values for the new column added to the model, even though the column is present in the database from the start. So you need to add a default value, mine was an Integerfield, so I updated my column definition in the model as IntegerField(default=0).
   From here onwards it should be straightforward, if there are no other errors.
2. *py -3 manage.py migrate*
3. *py -3 manage.py runserver*

After executing these steps when I called my REST APIs they were working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I created a model file for my app and then did several `sqlall` as I refined my tables. One of the changes I made was I set `primary_key=True` to one of my fields. At the end called for `syncdb`. Added a dummy value and and tried to access it with `User.objects.all()`, `User` being my model class. Although this worked fine, this error came up while printing the list returned by the `all()` call. It read `DatabaseError: (1054, "Unknown column 'polls_user.id' in 'field list'")`

Surprisingly, I tried and could get it resolved with another call to `syncdb`. I remember not having seen the id column in the table at any time throughout the exercise when I checked it through the mysql command line client.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error while trying to use Django Rest Framework serializers. Make sure if you have a serializer that subclasses `ModelSerializer`, that you migrate any changes to the Models before writing your serializer classes (or just comment anything related to the serializer, migrate, then uncomment).

Answer (score 0):

PS F:\WebApp> python manage.py makemigrations
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'price' to destination without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 2
PS F:\WebApp> python manage.py sqlmigrate travello 0001

### BEGIN;

### -- Create model Destination

CREATE TABLE `travello_destination` (`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL, `img` varchar(100) NOT NULL, `desc` longtext NOT NULL, `offer` bool NOT NULL);
COMMIT;
PS F:\WebApp> python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'travello':
  travello\migrations\0002_destination_price.py
    - Add field price to destination
PS F:\WebApp> python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, travello
Running migrations:
  Applying travello.0002_destination_price... OK

Comment: if you you want to add extra field like price into mysql db.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when using a composite Primary Key of several `VarChar` fields and trying to call a `table_set.all()` queryset. 
Django wanted a `table_name_id` PK column for this queryset, there wasn't one so it threw out this error. 
I fixed it by manually creating the `table_name_id` and setting it to an auto-incremented, integer PK column instead of the composite PK. 
I then specified those `VarChar` composite columns as `unique_together` in the Model's meta section so they act like a PK.

Answer (score 0):

The model of the app which has that field you have to run two commands.

```
python manage.py migrate appname zero
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score -2):

The direct solution is delete files under folder ../Project/App/migrations, and the method to avoid this problem is create new databaes table column instead of chagne the existing one.