# retrieve record from database using django

Tags: python, django

My task is to to retrieve data from database and show it in an HTML table. I am using a few columns from the database to show in the page, but its is not giving a result. Please tell me what I should do. It's giving me a blank table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/css/style.css"/>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title> MY Site

            </title>
            </head>

        <body>
            <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                  <img src="/static/images/django-logo.png" width="300px;" height="75px" >


            </div>
            </div>

             <div class="content">

              <table border="1" style= "background-color:white; width:60%"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="" >

              <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>tb_Name </th>
              <th>Product_name </th>
              <th>Domain_name </th>
              </tr>

              {% for key in Testbeds %}
                  <tr>
                  <td>{{ key.name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ key.tb_name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ key.product_name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ key.domain_name }}</td>
                  </tr>
              {% endfor %}

              </table>
            </div>

            <div class="footer">
              <p> copy right django.com </p>
            </div>

            </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse,get_object_or_404
from datetime import datetime
from blog.models import Testbeds

  def base(request):

    obj =  Testbeds.objects.all()
    return render (request, 'base.html', {'obj': obj})
```

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from blog import views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^base/$', 'blog.views.base', name="base"),
    #url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', 'blog.views.post'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return render (request, 'base.html', {'obj': obj})
```

With this line, you are sending a variable called `obj` to your template - not one called `Testbeds`. Change `Testbeds` in your template to `obj`.

```
{% for o in obj %}
      <tr> 
          <td>{{ o.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ o.tb_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ o.product_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ o.domain_name }}</td>
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's the problem, but I'd suggest that changing the view so you can loop through through `{% for testbed in testbed %}` in the template would be better.

Comment: OperationalError at /base/
(1054, "Unknown column 'blog_testbeds.gateway_name' in 'field list'")

Comment: Do you have a column called gateway_name in your model?

Comment: @sufyanshahid It's not your view. Take a look here first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787237/django-models-1054-unknown-column-in-field-list